# C socket trouble

Tags: c, sockets

I start study sockets and I have trouble!
What do I do wrong?

Server:

```
/* server.c */

/* ############### INCLUDES ############### */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

/* ############### DEFINES ############### */

// Check OS
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
    #define OS 1 // WINDOWS
#else
    #define OS 0 // LINUX || UNIX
#endif

#define MAX_CLIENT 100
#define NAME_SIZE 32
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

/* ############### FUNCTIONS PRE-DEFINITIONS ############### */

void error (char *msg);
void clearScreen (void);

/* ############### STRUCTURES ############### */                    

struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

/* ############### VARIABLES ############### */

int server_accept = 0;
int bytes_read = 0;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
char msg[BUFFER_SIZE] = "Hello from server\n";

/* ############### MAIN FUNCTION ############### */

int main (void)
{
    int server_desk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create socket
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    clearScreen();

    if (server_desk < 0)
        error("[!] Socket");
    else
        fputs("[*] Socket for server was create.\n" ,stdout);

    if ((bind(server_desk, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr,
                sizeof(server_addr))) < 0) // Bind socket
        error("[!] Bind");
    else
        fputs("[*] Bind done.\n" ,stdout);

    if ((listen(server_desk, 1)) < 0)
        error("[!] Listen");
    else
        fputs("[*] Listening...\n\n" ,stdout);


    while ((strcmp(buffer, "/shutdown\n")) != 0)
    {
        if ((server_accept = accept(server_desk, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
            error("[!] Accept");
        else
            fputs("[*] Client connected.\n", stdout);

        while(1)
        {
            bytes_read = recv(server_accept, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
            if (bytes_read == 0)
            {
                fputs("[*] Client disconected.\n", stdout);
                break;
            }
            else if (bytes_read < 0)
            {
                error("[!] Recv");
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "[Chat] > %s", buffer);
                send(server_accept, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
            }
        }
        close(server_accept);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* ############### FUNCTIONS LOGIC ############### */

void clearScreen (void)
{
    #if (OS == 0)
        system("clear");
    #else
        system("cls");
    #endif

    return;
}

/* error - print error message and exit failure */
void error (char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
    return;
}
```

Client:

```
/* client.c */

/* ############### INCLUDES ############### */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

/* ############### DEFINES ############### */

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

/* ############### FUNCTIONS PRE-DEFINITIONS ############### */

void error (char *msg);

/* ############### MAIN FUNCTION ############### */

int main (void)
{
    system("clear || cls");
    char msg[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    int client_desk = 0;
    int client_connect = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    client_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    client_desk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create socket
    if (client_desk < 0)
        error("[!] Socket");

    client_connect = connect(client_desk, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr,
                             sizeof(client_addr));
    if (client_connect < 0)
        error("[!] Connect");

    fputs("[Chat] < ", stdout);
    fgets(msg, (sizeof(msg)), stdin);

    send(client_connect, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    recv(client_connect, buffer, sizeof(msg), 0);
    fprintf(stdout, "[Chat] > %s", buffer);

    close(client_connect);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* ############### FUNCTIONS LOGIC ############### */

void error (char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
    return;
}
```

I need to send message to server and get answer. But server do not send message to client.

And I don't understand how bind ip address for server, for example `192.168.0.50:8080`

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "[Chat] > %s", buffer);` --> `buffer` is not certainly null character terminated.  Better to inspect the return value of `recv()`.  Something like `ssize_t sz = recv(client_connect, buffer, sizeof buffer -
 1, 0); if (sz >= 0) { buffer[sz] = 0; puts(buffer);}`

Comment: `recv()` returns 0 if the peer disconnects. You should be checking for `> 0` instead of `>= 0`. And you don't need to append a null-terminator. Pass the return value of `recv()` as a parameter to `fprintf()` instead: `printf("[Chat] > %.*s", sz, buffer); `

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think you want `printf(stdout, "[Chat] > %.*s", (int) sz, buffer);`  cast and `.` added.

Comment: @oyaro `sizeof buffer - 1` is quite different than `sizeof(buffer - 1)`.  The first is the size of the array minus 1, then 2nd is the size of a pointer.

Comment: @chux: you are right about the `.`, but the cast is not needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `*` expects an `int`, so if `sz` is not an `int`, something must be done.

Comment: Okey. Why I have this error? `[!] Recv: Socket operation on non-socket`

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the client addr here:

```
client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
```

Replace with this line with the one below with the IP address of the server:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.50", &(client.sin_addr));
```

This will set the addr to be the server so that when you connect, you are connecting to the IP address of the server instead of INADDR. You already have the port set so you should be good with that.

**The main structure of basic client/server is that the server bind's and accepts connection from INADDR_ANY with the client must define the IP it wants to connect to using the above code snippet.**